# Derivative words from verb

Tags: word-request

I want to make a word derived from the word "*verb*" as a predicate to mean that something has connotations associated with verbs.

My difficulty is that I do not want the derived word to be mistaken with associations related to the word "*verbal*" instead.

Comment: Not sure I understand but here goes: verb-related [x].

Comment: I came up with `Verbial`, `Verbatic`. Would these make sense ? Would they constitute valid words?

Comment: I repeat: I have no idea what your purpose or meaning is. No, those are not in the dictionary but you can make up what you like.

Comment: What could be in a dictionary from the word `verb` ?  Cannot find much.

Comment: I am quite sure that the derived word `verbial` to mean `of the nature of a verb` is valid.  Have taken this derivation from `proverbial` that means `of the nature of a proverb`.

Comment: You will probably be closed out because your question makes little sense. Verb-like associations.

Comment: Why does it not make sense making a derived from `verb` ?  Of course one can.

Comment: This site is for questions from people who want to learn English. Inventing new words is not part of learning English. If you are requesting an English word that has a specific meaning, then explain the meaning of the word you'd like us to give you. Am I right that you want a word that means *[of, relating to, or formed from a verb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/verbal)* but does not have other confusing meanings like "verbal" does?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: "Verby" or "Verbish" would be understood; but questions about making stuff up belong on Writing SE not here.

Answer (score 2):

The word '*verbal*' means 'related to words', and you're looking for a word that suggests the meaning 'related to verbs', specifically?

As Lambie pointed out in a [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/342011/derivative-words-from-verb#comment657064_342011), '***verb-related***' is obvious in meaning and grammatically correct.

With your neologisms like '*verbial*' and '*verbatic*' you risk confusing your readers.

Comment: proverbial does not have confusions though.

Comment: Unlike ordinary verbs, verbals are not inflected for person and tense. As an adjective, the term verbal can mean (1) relating to words (as in verbal irony), (2) spoken rather than written (as in "a verbal agreement"), or (3) relating to or formed from a verb (as in verbal noun).  Meaning that `verbal` should be quite a valid term.

Comment: @Bhimas Yes, but the first meaning is the most common, so you'd likely still have to point out that you are referring to that third meaning.

Comment: I would agree with you.  I would need to point out what I am referring to.  Besides, in the linguistic sense, `tense` is not completely associated with verbs only.  Many teachers of English have never been exposed to any linguistic analysis and keep seeing many using terminology in a very loose sense.  This is what actually produces confusions to English Learners.